# Custom taxonomy archive is visible to only subscibed users

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, user-roles

I have a custom taxonomy (lesson) that helps divide posts and other custom post types between different views over the data. Now I have the custom taxonomy page expanded and visible.

http://www.ascuoladiopencoesione.it/lesson/1-progettare/

You should see an empty page, and that is the issue: Only registered users appear to be able to see the content, and that is strange, because the configuration does not do anything to enforce that...

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is the structure for  the Custom Taxonomy. The custom post type is portfolio_entry, in a theme (enfold)... for other taxonomies and stuff there is no problem, only this doesn't work...

```
function lessons() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Lessons', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Lesson', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Lesson Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( '', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( '', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add new Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Lessons with commas', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'has_archive'                => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true
);
register_taxonomy( 'lesson', array( 'post','portfolio','link_category', 'forum', "topic" ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'lessons', 0 );
```

**EDIT added plugins**

- bbPress
- Black Studio TinyMCE Widget
- Duplicate Post
- Google Analytics for WordPress
- MailChimp for WordPress Lite
- Page Builder by SiteOrigin
- Responsive Add Ons
- Simple History
- User Role Editor
- User Tags for Wordpress
- Widget Customizer
- WordPress Social Login
- WP Project Manager
- Newsletters Wysija

**EDIT - how do I get the posts**

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'lesson'           => $wp_query->queried_object->name,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => array('post', 'portfolio', 'forum', 'link', 'topic', 'link_category'),
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true ); 
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
```

Comment: Can you show us the code how you've registered the post type and taxonomy?

Comment: I have added the details on how I instantiate the taxonomy...

Comment: Are you certain that there are no plugins causing this issue? Could you edit your question and list the plugins you have installed? Can you disable all your plugins to see if that changes the situation?

Comment: Where do you call this function?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I cannot disable them, but I'll add the list.

Comment: @Horttcore the function is called in the functions.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not in the world know why this works. Yet it does. For future reference...

```
function remove_meta( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_query', false );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_meta' );
```